I just try to do dual boot on my laptop win 11 with ubuntu and after that in ubuntu os (24.04 LTS) screen brightness can't be controllable, solution?
I have a ASUS TUF A15 gaming laptop with NVDIA 3050 gpu with amd integrated GPU, now I try to do dual boot on this laptop with ubuntu, but after do that when I open ubuntu the screen brightness is very low but if I connect with charger and reboot the system(without rebooting the brightness will not increase after laptop is on charging mode) then it will be normal but not controllable means I can't up down the brightness. But on windows everything is normal means no brightness issue.Ubuntu works fine and I have to connect to charger to get brightness high(max) otherwise its too dim.

You can use the xrandr command to adjust the brightness
In your terminal type:
xrandr --output xyz --brightness <value>

replace xyz with your username and <value> with the level of brightness you want ranging from 0.1 (dim) to 1.0 (full brightness).

Ubuntu works fine and I have to connect to charger to get brightness high(max) otherwise its too dim.

Make sure to update NVIDIA graphics drivers. Ensure that you are using the latest NVIDIA proprietary drivers.

Add the official NVIDIA PPA and update.
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt update


Install the recommended driver for your GPU (e.g., 3050).
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall


Reboot your system.
sudo reboot




I have tried this but nothing happend still have the issue
